# images are not loading in jquery/json slider

Tags: jquery, json, slider

I want to acheive jquery slider with external json file,slider is working properly,but when page loads only button of slider appear and image appears after the clicking of button,can anyone sort out the problem?

**HTML**

```
<div id="update">

</div>
<!--div block which is to be updated by jquery --->

<script src=" https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js "></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON('data.json', function (data) {
            var output = '<div class="slideshow-container">';
            $.each(data.data, function (key, value) {
                output += '<div class="mySlides fade">';
                output += '<h3 class="numbertext"> Location:   ' + value.location + '</h3>';
                output += '<img src="' + value.links.logo2x + '" style="width:100%;"/>';
                output += '<div class="text"> Name:   ' + value.name + '</div>';
                output += '<div class="desc">' + value.description + '</div>';
                output += '</div>'; /*myslides*/
            });
            output += '<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">' + '&#10094;' + '</a>';
            output += '<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">' + '❯' + '</a>';
            output += '</div>';
            $('#update').html(output);
        });
    });
```

**Javascript code**

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    if (n > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1
    }
    if (n < 1) {
        slideIndex = slides.length
    }
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }

}
```

**CSS**

```
body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   background-color: #dad7c7;
   font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
   line-height: 1.2em;
}

* {
   box-sizing: border-box
}

.slideshow-container {
   width: 520px;
   position: relative;
   margin: 0 auto;
   max-width: 100%;
}

.mySlides {
   display: none;
   max-width: 100%;
}

mySlides img {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}

.prev,
.next {
   cursor: pointer;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   width: auto;
   padding: 16px;
   margin-top: -22px;
   color: white;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 18px;
   transition: 0.6s ease;
   border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
   border: 1px solid white;
}

.text {
   color: #f2f2f2;
   font-size: 16px;
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 30px;
   text-align: center;
   background-color: black;
   padding-top: 5px;
   text-transform: uppercase;
}
/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
   right: 0;
   border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.numbertext {
   color: #f2f2f2;
   font-size: 12px;
   padding: 8px 12px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
   background-color: black;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

.desc {
   position: absolute;
   color: #968888;
   line-height: 1.5em;
   padding: 10px;
   background-color: white;
   font-weight: 700;
   height: auto;
   overflow: auto;
   transition: all .3s ease;
}

.desc:hover {
   box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
/* Fading animation */

.fade {
   -webkit-animation-name: fade;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
   animation-name: fade;
   animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
   from {
       opacity: .4
   }
   to {
       opacity: 1
   }
}

@-moz-keyframes fade {
   from {
       opacity: .4
   }
   to {
       opacity: 1
   }
}
```

On page loads only button appears

[image]

After clicking on the button image loads

[image]

Comment: Please help i am not able to sort out this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's normal because in your function `showSlides` you hide all img with for loop: Please try

```
function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    if (n > slides.length) {
       slideIndex = 1
    }
    if (n < 1) {
       slideIndex = slides.length
    }
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slides[n].style.display = "block";
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

I have found! The problem is because your slides script start before the inner script. I have add this into a function and call this after element created. 
Please try:

```js
function showThis(){
  $(document).on("click",".prev",function(){
    plusSlides(-1)
  })
  $(document).on("click",".next",function(){
    plusSlides(1)
  })
  var slideIndex = 1;
  showSlides(slideIndex);

  function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
  }

  function currentSlide(n) {
     showSlides(slideIndex = n);
  }

  function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = $(".mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    if (n > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1
    }
    if (n < 1) {
        slideIndex = slides.length
    }
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";

  }
}
```

```css
body {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     background-color: #dad7c7;
     font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
     line-height: 1.2em;
 }
 
 * {
     box-sizing: border-box
 }
 
 .slideshow-container {
     width: 520px;
     position: relative;
     margin: 0 auto;
     max-width: 100%;
 }
 
 .mySlides {
     display: none;
     max-width: 100%;
 }
 
 mySlides img {
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
 }
 
 .prev,
 .next {
     cursor: pointer;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     width: auto;
     padding: 16px;
     margin-top: -22px;
     color: white;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 18px;
     transition: 0.6s ease;
     border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
     background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
     border: 1px solid white;
 }
 
 .text {
     color: #f2f2f2;
     font-size: 16px;
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     height: 30px;
     text-align: center;
     background-color: black;
     padding-top: 5px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
 }
 /* Position the "next button" to the right */
 
 .next {
     right: 0;
     border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
 }
 /* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
 
 .numbertext {
     color: #f2f2f2;
     font-size: 12px;
     padding: 8px 12px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     width: 100%;
     text-align: center;
     background-color: black;
     margin: 0 auto;
 }
 
 .desc {
     position: absolute;
     color: #968888;
     line-height: 1.5em;
     padding: 10px;
     background-color: white;
     font-weight: 700;
     height: auto;
     overflow: auto;
     transition: all .3s ease;
 }
 
 .desc:hover {
     box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
 }
 /* Fading animation */
 
 .fade {
     -webkit-animation-name: fade;
     -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
     animation-name: fade;
     animation-duration: 1.5s;
 }
 
 @-webkit-keyframes fade {
     from {
         opacity: .4
     }
     to {
         opacity: 1
     }
 }
 
 @-moz-keyframes fade {
     from {
         opacity: .4
     }
     to {
         opacity: 1
     }
 }
 
 @-o-keyframes fade {
     from {
         opacity: .4
     }
     to {
         opacity: 1
     }
 }
 
 @keyframes fade {
     from {
         opacity: .4
     }
     to {
         opacity: 1
     }
 }
 /**media queries **/
 
 @media (max-width:562px) {
     div.desc {
         height: 200px !important;
         overflow: auto !important;
         line-height: 1.2em;
         border-bottom: 2px solid #5D5D5D;
         text-align: justify;
     }
     .prev,
     .next {
         padding: 8px;
         font-size: 15px;
     }
     body::-webkit-scrollbar {
         width: 1em;
     }
     body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
         -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
     }
     body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
         background-color: indianred;
         outline: 1px solid slategrey;
     }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="update">

    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
              output ="";
                    output += '<div class="mySlides fade">';
                    output += '<h3 class="numbertext"> Location:  </h3>';
                    output += '<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/6/63/IMG_(business).svg/1280px-IMG_(business).svg.png" style="width:100%;"/>';
                    output += '<div class="text"> </div>';
                    output += '<div class="desc"></div>';
                    output += '</div>'; /*myslides*/
                     output += '<div class="mySlides fade">';
                    output += '<h3 class="numbertext"> Location:  </h3>';
                    output += '<img src="https://media.licdn.com/media/AAEAAQAAAAAAAANbAAAAJDE5NjBkNDk1LTY3ZGQtNDA0NS04YTJiLTdkNmU3NjZiNjI3Mg.png" style="width:100%;"/>';
                    output += '<div class="text"> </div>';
                    output += '<div class="desc"></div>';
                    output += '</div>'; /*myslides*/
                     

                output += '<a class="prev" >' + '&#10094;' + '</a>';
                output += '<a class="next" >' + '❯' + '</a>';
                output += '</div>';
                $('#update').html(output);
          showThis();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: but now also all the images are not loading only buttons are Loading

Comment: can you create a snippet or fiddle with your issue?

Comment: have you put your function into document.ready()? if no, insert it

Comment: but how can i create fiddle because all the data is coming from json file

Comment: no,because the function is in vanilla javascript,but html is embeded in jquery

Comment: P,Frank please see my fiddle

Comment: now the button are also not working,i have all the json data into local file and m trying to fetch data from $.getJSON

Comment: For yours clicks "plusslides" etc..  put it directly in script showThis() with jquery event click $(document).on("click",".plusSlides",function(){})

Comment: i am not able to understand,can you please tell specific,Thanks

Comment: hello P.frank,Images are working now but but the prev and next buttons are not working

Comment: Thanks P.frank,i want to enhance my js skills,Please give any link of tutorial,thanks alot

Comment: I have remove the `output += '<a class="prev" >' + '&#10094;' + '</a>';`  and `output += '<a class="next" >' + '&#10094;' + '</a>';` onclick and detect click with jquery

Comment: The best site is http://www.w3schools.com/js/.  If your issue is resolved, please valid this. Thanks